# Inequality involving convolutions

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, examples-counterexamples, convolution

We  have well known inequality for convolution: $\|g\ast f\|_{X} \leq \|g\|_{Y} \|f\|_{Z}$ where $Y, X, Z$ are suitable Lebesgue spaces, e.g., see [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality).

Let $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb C, K:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ ( assume that $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^2)$ (Schwartz space), $K\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$),
We define convolution in the following sense:
$$F(x,y) =\int_{\mathbb R} [K(x-z)-K(y-z)] f(z,z) dz$$

> Can we  expect to find  norm linear spaces   $(X,  \|\cdot\|_{X}), (Y, \|\cdot\|_{Y}$  consists of functions on $\mathbb R^2$  and  norm space  $(Z, \|\cdot\|)$  consists of functions on $\mathbb R$
>   so that 
>   $$\|F\|_{X} \leq C \|K\|_{Z} \|f\|_{Y}$$?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but only the values of $f$ on the diagonal is used. Its more natural therefore to use $g(z) = f(z,z)$ and look for results for the one variable function $g$. Then your $F(x,y)$ is just

$$ F(x,y) =  K*g(x) - K*g(y)$$

and for example, we have the crude estimate
$$ |K*g(x) - K*g(y)| = \left| \int_y^x K'*g \right| \le \int_{\mathbb R }|K'*g|$$

This implies 
$$ \|F\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^2)} \le \|K'*g\|_{L^1} \le \|K\|_{W^{1,p}} \|g\|_{L^q}$$
for suitable $p,q$ via Young's inequality.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand your second step: that is, ..=$\int_y^x K'\ast g$? ($K'$ is  the derivative of $K$?) Please can  you explain a bit? Do I need to use mean value theorem or so? Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner yes, using $K*g'=K'*g = (K*g)'$ and integral mean value theorem (that is, fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is there any way to get  the estimate for $\|\hat{F}\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^2)}$ ($\hat{F}$ is the  Fourier transform of $F$)? I'm curious to know this. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner the two variable fourier transform is not locally integrable, as a distribution if $(\xi,\eta)$ are the frequency variables it is $$\hat F (\xi,\eta) =  \hat K(\xi) \hat g(\xi) \delta_0(\eta) - \hat K(\eta)\hat g(\eta) \delta_0(\xi)$$

Comment: @CK:Thaks. From  $\widehat{F},$ we may get, $\|\hat{F}\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^2)} \leq \|\hat{K}\hat{g}\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)} \|\delta_0\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)} \leq 0$,  (Is $\|\delta_0\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)}=0$?), and so we get $\hat{F}=0$ and  so $F=0$ a.e. (I'm sure, I'm doing something wrong). Can tell me where the arguments goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner no, $\delta_0$ is not a function, it doesn't have an $L^1$ norm. Its the linear functional in $\mathcal S'$ defined by
$$\mathcal S \ni \phi \mapsto \delta_0(\phi) := \langle \delta_0,\phi\rangle := \phi(0) \in \mathbb C $$
admittedly I used the sloppy physicist notation above, but the quantity $\delta_0 (\eta)$ cannot be interpreted in the normal way, it is defined only when it appears in an integral against a function in $\mathcal S$

$$ \int \delta_0(\eta) \phi(\eta) d\eta := \phi(0)$$